# Quit foreground programs at RDP logoff

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-server-2003

I have some running foreground programs that I wish to finish even if I log off my RDP session. For some reason if I log off for too long and come back, everything is gone, including open folders and text files. This doesn't happen if I log back on immediately.

Is there a group policy or other setting that's telling Windows to close all my programs after I log off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/99258/remote-desktop-sessions-unwanted-automatic-log-off-after-period-of-time) covers your options I believe.